# NetBeans and Python

Tags: python, netbeans

When I run some python code in NetBeans, which raises an error, the output in NetBeans just gives an error message and no further information, such as line number. Is there any way to fix that?

Answer (score 1):

If you can, I would run your script outside of NetBeans either with the built-in editor (IDLE) or just run it from the command line.  That should give you a traceback with the error and lineno

NetBeans has issues with debugging, as [other posts suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1972049/unable-to-get-netbeans-debugger-working-for-python).

Answer (score 0):

added solution is debugging if don't have any compiling error